# Google Cloud Storage delete objects with archived files

Tags: google-cloud-storage, delete-file, bucket

What happens if you have a Google Cloud Storage bucket with files in Archive storage (or any other storage class that charges for deleted files), and then you delete the bucket?

Do you still get charged for the deleted files, or not (since the bucket got deleted)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt to delete a bucket with objects in it, the attempt will fail with a "Bucket Not Empty" error. You must delete each object individually before deleting the bucket. Any early deletion fees will still be incurred regardless of whether you follow up on deleting the object by deleting the bucket.